# Regex not replacing desired string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to remove the letter 's' from the end of any string that follows this rule:

There must be a vowel somewhere in the word that isn't in the second to last location. There can be a vowel in the second to last position in the string, but the 's' will not be removed if the only vowel is in the second to last position.

For example:

gas -> would not get changed because the only vowel 'a' is in the position right before the 's'

toys -> would become 'toy'

examples -> example because there is a vowel (e,a) in the word before the s, and not only in the second to last position.

Now I have a method in a class class called Tokenizer.java

```
public String remove(String word){

        //replace any words that end with s if the preceding word part contains a vowel not immediately before the 's'                                                                                   
        word.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou][a-z]*[a-rt-z])s\\b", "$1");   

        return word; 
}
```

and I call this method in my tester.java class
package tokenizer;

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        String word = token.deleteS("causes"); 
        System.out.println(word);
        word = token.remove("examples"); 
        System.out.println(word);
        word = token.deleteS("toys"); 
        System.out.println(word);
        word = token.deleteS("gas"); 
        System.out.println(word);

    }

}
```

my output:

```
causes
examples
toys
gas
```

expected output:

```
cause
example
toy
gas
```

The issue I am having is that when I test it on this [regex 101 link](https://regex101.com/r/zD3yZ7/1), I see that it is working. Why is it acting differently in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace following line in your method

```
word.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou][a-z]*[a-rt-z])s\\b", "$1");
```

with

```
word = word.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou][a-z]*[a-rt-z])s\\b", "$1");
```

or remove it and leave this as body of function

```
return word.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou][a-z]*[a-rt-z])s\\b", "$1");
```

methods of string function doesn't affect string itself just return result as **string** so you need to intercept this new string by assigning it to same or new variable

Comment: Thank you. Very silly oversight on my part. Have been at this for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public String remove(String word){

        return word.replaceAll("(?i)([aeiou][a-z]*[a-rt-z])s\\b", "$1");  

}
```